# Payload js descrypting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I doing a code with angular, and in one case the json returns one value like a payload and I need to decrypt that.
I have a payload that like that:
[image]

I need to decode that. Like the following way:
For example the part $B the vaule I need only the value 14, for the $s the value -58,etc.
And I don't know hoy I can do it. For the moment only I split for the $.

```
 var payload = event.eventpayload;
 var dec = payload.split("$");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always only one char after the `$`, you can do something like this

```
var eventpayload="$ST$I0$O0$B14.00$M1$S-58$D0000.03$X_"
var earr = eventpayload.split("$").splice(1);
obj={};
for (var i=0; i < earr.length; i++) {
    obj[earr[i][0]] = earr[i].slice(1);
}
console.log(obj);
```

you can also parseFloat() all values like this

```
var eventpayload="$ST$I0$O0$B14.00$M1$S-58$D0000.03$X_"
var earr = eventpayload.split("$").splice(1);
obj={};
for (var i=0; i < earr.length; i++) {
    obj[earr[i][0]] = parseFloat(earr[i].slice(1));
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to retrieve the values and then loop through the matches to create a dictionary.

Sample in C#:

```
const string payload = "$ST$I0$O0$B14.00$M1$S-058$D0000.03$X_";
var re = new Regex(@"(?<key>\$[A-Z])(?<value>[^$]*)");
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(payload)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
$S: T
$I: 0
$O: 0
$B: 14.00
$M: 1
$S: -058
$D: 0000.03
$X: _
```